# OpenGL dynamic CPU skinning not rendering

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, opengl

I have a really obscure problem that I hope somebody can help with. I have implemented vertex skinning on the CPU (the GPU was too slow because the bad performance of looking up a bone transform in a vertex shader) using a background thread on OSX. I do not need a shared context because no GL calls are made. I allocate a buffer in the process heap big enough to hold my character's vertices. I skin and animate that buffer on the background thread. In the main thread I simply glBufferSubData() that buffer down to my VBO, synchronizing with the end of the buffer update so I don't get tearing in my verts. The VBO has previously been bound to a VAO (one VAO per VBO per character instance). So I only have to bind the VAO and draw my mesh. Not very difficult so far. A single IBO is bound to all VAO's per character instance.

Here's the rub. If I only have one character instance the code works perfectly. I have a lovely little warrior princess doing her idle animation. The moment I add a second instance nothing happens--only the first instance renders.

So the big question is what am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure my VBO, IBO and VAOs are correct. There's a separate VBO and VAO per instance. I turned off indexing (no IBO) and still the instances fail to draw so it's not that IMHO. I've verified the state using the Mac OpenGL Profiler and everything looks good per instance. Is there some kind of weird flushing not going on due to my glBufferSubData call. glMapBuffer was just too slow!

If you need source code to look at I can upload that easily enough. Just wondering if anyone's heard of weirdness like what I'm seeing when dealing with buffer objects in OpenGL on the Mac.

Comment: Figured it out. The VAOs were not set up properly in the other characters because I wasn't binding the IBO to them. A typo in the code.